# with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r','utf-8') as file: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: nlp, typeerror, nltk

why iam getting this error

```
import os
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Get a list of English stop words
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

# Set the input and output directories
input_dir = 'C:\\Users\\acer\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\extracted_data'
output_dir = 'C:\\Users\\acer\OneDrive\\Desktop\\cleaned extracted data'

# Iterate over the files in the input directory
for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
    # Read the text file
    with open(os.path.join(input_dir, filename), 'r','utf-8') as file:
        text = file.read()

    # Split the text into a list of words
    words = text.split()

    # Remove punctuation from each word
    words = [word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for word in words]

    # Remove stop words from the list of words
    cleaned_words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stop_words]

    # Join the cleaned words into a single string
    cleaned_text = ' '.join(cleaned_words)

    # Write the cleaned text to a new file
    with open(os.path.join(output_dir, filename), 'w',"utf-8") as file:
        file.write(cleaned_text)
```

this is my code,i was cleaning my extracted data from a website using stopwords suddenly this error occured

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the error by importing codecs. If you want to open a binary file in read mode and specify the encoding, you can use the codecs module like this:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') 
as file:
```